# howto generate associated admin models in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, action, models

i've an rails application where the `CUD (create, update, delete)` actions only can used by the admin to create update or delete an item. The show (read) action can used by everyone.

Now i want that only the admin create other entries. this is my item model

```
    class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :entries
```

And this is my entry model

```
    class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :item
```

In my admin_controller for the items i have the need actions.

```
    class Admin::ItemsController < ApplicationController
```

Now i have two questions

1. My question is, have i to define an own admin entry controller? I
   think yes, there is an own admin-item-controller needed.
2. How is the best way to define that the item_admin is allow to
   create, update or delete the entries. everyone else can the entries
   only see. can every help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are two options:

1. Build an admin/items and an admin/entries controller that allow all `CRUD` operations - but for admins only. In addition have a public items and an public entries controller that have only the `show` method implemented.
2. Have only one controller per type (no dedicated admin controller). Within this controller use gems like `pundit` or `cancancan` to ensure that only admins can use the `create`, `update` and `destroy` action.

Comment: Hello @spickermann, i'll try the option 1. Thanks for your help